# How to get part of the string that matched with regular expression in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Lets say I have following string: 'product=1627;color=45;size=7' in some field of the table.
I want to query for the color and get 45.

With this query:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('product=1627;color=45;size=7', 'color\=([^;]+);?') "colorID" 
FROM DUAL;
```

I get :

```
colorID  
---------
color=45;
1 row selected
```

.

Is it possible to get part of the matched string - 45 for this example?

Comment: SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR('product=1627;color=45;size=7', 'color\=([^;]+);?'), '\d+') "colorID" FROM DUAL;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do it is with REGEXP_REPLACE.  You need to define the whole string as a regex pattern and then use just the element you want as the `replace string`.  In this example the ColorID is the third pattern in the entire string

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('product=1627;color=45;size=7'
                         , '(.*)(color\=)([^;]+);?(.*)'
                         , '\3') "colorID"  
FROM DUAL;
```

It is possible there may be less clunky regex solutions, but this one definitely works.  [Here's a SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7dc03/1)

Comment: or `'.*color\=([^;]+).*', '\1'`

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR('product=1627;color=45;size=7', 'color\=([^;]+);?'), '[[:digit:]]+') "colorID"
FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 11g onwards we can specify capture groups in [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm#SQLRF06303).

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('product=1627;color=45;size=7', 'color=(\d+);', 1, 1, 'i', 1) "colorID" 
FROM DUAL;
```